# Arquitetura Banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Galera estou com uma dúvida com respeito a banco de dados. Tenho um usuário X que vai poder encaminhar uma mensagem para N outros usuário. Qual a melhor forma desse tipo de relacionamento? Devo criar uma tabela e inserir cada Usuário (id) destinatário junto com o Usuário(id) que enviou?

Comment: Acho que sim, mas é difícil dizer ao certo só com isso.

Comment: Na verdade a principio será só isso na tabela mesmo kkk xD

Comment: Então não tem dúvida nenhuma?

Comment: @bigown acho que o que ele está tentando explicar seria como um sistema de comunicado em um app, onde um administrar dispara uma mensagem para todos os membros.

Answer (score 1):

Pensando em um cenário bem simples, faria em apenas uma tabela:

```
Mensagens
id   |   data        |   remetente  | destinatário  | mensagem  | lida
 1       01/01/2017             1      2               Teste       false
 2       01/01/2017             1      3               Teste       true
 3       01/01/2017             1      4               Teste       false
 4       01/01/2017             1      5               Teste       true
 5       01/01/2017             1      6               Teste       false
```

Mas se complicar a situação, dependendo do número de destinatários, etc...
aí deveria ser feito em duas tabelas para manter a forma normal e não ter dados redundantes.